# path seperator in vim

Tags: path

I have a vim script, which uses Unix type path separator as:

```
"Prg: Expand snippets {{{!
let s:plugin_dir=filter(split(&rtp, ','), 'v:val =~ "/vimf90"')[0]
let s:templatedir=s:plugin_dir . '/templates/'
function! Prog(arg)
  execute 'r ' . s:templatedir . a:arg . '.txt'
  %substitute#\[:EVAL:\]\(.\{-\}\)\[:END:\]#\=eval(submatch(1))#ge
endfunction
"}}}
"
```

I have never used Windows, so I was not aware that it may break in Windows. One of my users reported this issue:

> The script works very well on Linux system, but when I try it on
>   Windows, it does not work with the following error:
>
> ```
> ================================================= 
> Error detected while processing
> C:\User\Ki-Tae\vimfiles\plugged\vimf90\ftplugin\fortran_comp.vim: line
> 102: E684: list index out of range: 0 E15: Invalid expression:
> filter(split(&rtp, ','), 'v:val =~ "/vimf90"')[0] line 103: E121:
> Undefined variable: s:plugin_dir E15: Invalid expression: s:plugin_dir
> . '/templates/'
> =================================================
> ```

Also, he was kind enough to send me back the solution as:

> In Windows, forward slash should be backward slash, so the code should
>   be
>
> ```
> filter(split(&rtp, ','), 'v:val =~ "\vimf90"')[0]
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> s:plugin_dir . '\templates\'
> ```

Which he claims to work for him.

As far as I know, [vim should alter the path separators inherently](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/OS-agnostic-path-separator-td1187176.html). But, clearly, this is not the case here.

The complete code in question is available [here](https://github.com/rudrab/vimf90/blob/master/ftplugin/fortran_comp.vim).

I will be grateful if someone kindly check this. I can't do that since I don't have any access to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I'd either make sure that neither `/` nor `\` are in the `&isk`(momentarily), then match `\<vimf90\>`, or I'd match `[/\\]` (`[/\\\\]` actually because of `filter()`) -- I've plenty examples in [path.vim](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/path.vim) module from my lh-vim-lib library plugin.

In mu-template, I didn't have your problem as I don't restrict my search for matching directories to `{rtp}/somethinghardcoded/templates`, [but only to `{rtp}/templates`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/blob/master/autoload/lh/mut/dirs.vim#L78). This way, overriding is possible, i.e., with `globpath(&rtp, 'templates')` end-users will be able to override your templates in their `$HOME/.vim/templates` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than explicitly specifying paths to the files you have in mind, try using built-in file path handling functions like `expand()` (potentially with `<sfile>`) or `glob()`/`globpath()`.

For instance, if you're looking for the root directory of your own plugin, you might try

```
let s:plugin_dir = expand("<sfile>:h:h")
```

I'm not sure how `glob` will work, but you could try

```
let s:templatedir = glob(s:plugin_dir . '/templates')
```

maybe ask your user to give it a shot and tell you how it works?

Comment: Remark, `expand('<sfile>')` needs to be executed at global script level, not within the scope of a function.